# Understanding mypy coverage report coloring (Any Types, Omitted Generics)

Tags: python, type-hinting, mypy

I'm getting started with type checking in Python and using the mypy tool. I've run a mypy html coverage report on a snippet of my code and see the following:

[image]

If I hover over this portion of the code it says "Any Types on this Line: Omitted Generics(x2)". My question is, what exactly does this mean? While mypy doesn't return any errors, I'm curious as to whether the fact that this is colored yellow means that I could (and should) do better so that it is colored green.

Answer (score 0):

First off, it's discouraged to just post images in your question - here it's useful because you're trying to figure out why your IDE is rendering something this way, but it would be very helpful to people who use screen readers to summarize what is going on in the image.

Second, you didn't mention which IDE generated the image you're looking at or the message that appears when you hover over it, so I can't help you with those specifics.

However, third, and hopefully this helps you actually resolve your confusion: `list[dict]` isn't the proper way to give mypy (or any other Python static typechecker for that matter) a type hint that this function returns a list. You should at mininum use `List[dict]` instead (`List` is provided by the `typing` library), or, for even more brownie points, be specific about what the dicts hold with `List[Dict[key_type, value_type]]`.

Comment: I'm not using an IDE. As noted, this is an html report (as visualized by any browser). As for your List[dict] comment, I believe that is incorrect for recent versions of Python (python 3.9 and above). See the cheat sheet here : https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/cheat_sheet_py3.html.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying what was generating the image. Mypy doesn't support that type of type hinting yet - I'm going to update my answer to give a bit more summary

Comment: Actually, nevermind, I was wrong. Have you tried adding `from __future__ import annotations` to the top of your file? For me, using Python 3.9.2 and mypy 0.812, without that line, mypy complains about the typehint, but when I add the future-annotations statement, it doesn't complain anymore. maybe that will help your HTML page as well?

Comment: I'm actually using Python 3.10, and mypy doesn't really complain (it tells me "Success: no issues found in 1 source file"), so I do not think I need the `__future__` import. Rather, it seems mypy is telling me something about the datetime.date type hint (which is why it's saying "x2"), but I don't understand exactly what it is telling me by "Omitted Generics" (both why is datetime.date a 'Generic' and what/why is it 'Omitted').

Answer (score 0):

Although I could not find it documented anywhere, the "Omitted Generics" corresponds to warnings that get silenced by the default settings.  If you use `mypy --strict` (or the equivalent setting in a config file, which is a good place to record the standards you're expecting from your code), you will find that many of these lines now be reported to be in error, with e.g. `Missing type parameters for generic type "MyType"  [type-arg]`, which will hopefully help you pinpoint the missing information.

Not all warnings implied in the HTML report are made visible by `--strict`, they will likely be exposed by increasing levels of strictness.  At this time (`mypy 0.990`) there does not seem to be an option that will cause all of those warnings to be reported, so finding the correct setting and deciding if you want seems to be "left as an exercise to the reader".